# Conversion from Postgresql to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, ssms

I'm using SSMS and am bringing in some data from PostgreSQL, the conversion I use in PostgreSQL doesn't work in SQL Server. The code converts data entry numbers into a smaller format that users can search on.  The code in PostgreSQL IS:

```
(substring(A."DATA_NUMBER"::text, 14, 2) || '-'::text) 
         || substring(a."DATA_NUMBER"::text, 2, 5) AS NEW_DATA
```

This is part of a much bigger query but this is the only part of it that doesn't work in SQL Server. I don't know much about conversion in SQL Server so it may be quite simple.

Comment: To try and put this into perspective the data entries come out of the system in this format '002095-13012016' it's a unique number and a date seperated by a '-' the format I need it to come out as is just the last 2 numbers of the year and the unique number seperated by a hyphen. So 002095-13012016 would come out as 16-002095.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substring an Convert are two different things. Please remove `::text` and replace `||` with `+` and try again.

"DATA_NUMBER" will be used as an Object-Identifier only, when the Setting `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is set to `ON`. If DATA_NUMBER is a column, I would write the code as follows:

```
(substring(A.DATA_NUMBER, 14, 2) + '-') 
         + substring(a.DATA_NUMBER, 2, 5) AS NEW_DATA
```

Comment: Changed it to:

    (substring(a."DATA_NUMBER", 14, 2) + '-') + substring(a."DATA_NUMBER", 2, 5) AS NEW_DATA

Still getting an error saying Data Number could not be bound.